# Force text inside 'example' environment to normal font

Tags: fonts

I am using 'amsthm'. I want the 'theorems' to appear italic font. However, I don't want the text in the 'example' to be in italics. How do I force this change?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.... Sorry to say that, from your `post`, it is very difficult to understand what you expected. Can you modify your `post` with more clearance....

Comment: Please tell us whether you employ the `amsthm` package or the `ntheorem` package (or possibly neither!) to help define theorem-like environments. Please also show the code you employ to create instances of `example` environments at present.

Comment: @Mico I am using the amsthm package.

Answer (score 3):

You mention in a comment that you employ the `amsthm` package. Here are a couple of excerpts from section 4, entitled "Changing styles for theorem-like environments", of the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) of the `amsthm` package (yellow highlighting added):

[image]

...

[image]

I thus suggest using the following as an outline of a guide toward achieving your formatting objective:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} % use 'plain' theorem style by default
\theoremstyle{definition} % switch to 'definition' theorem style
\newtheoerm{example}{Example}
```

These instructions should be placed in the preamble.